# Set focus on control inside iFrame jQuery

Tags: jquery

i was searching code to set focus on textbox in iframe and i found code like

```
//get the IFRAME element - note no hashes in the name, we're using browser functionality 

var iframeRef = document.getElementById("IFRAMEID"); 
//focus the IFRAME element 
$(iframeRef).focus(); 
//use JQuery to find the control in the IFRAME and set focus 
$(iframeRef).contents().find("#CONTROLID").focus();
```

but few people said this code does not work....so what would be the right code. thanks

Comment: Does this iframe content page have the same domain as the parent page?

Answer (score 1):

It'll only work if your iframe has the same domain as the parent window.

Comment: $(iframeRef).contents().find("#CONTROLID").focus();
what is .contents() here....plzz explain

Comment: `contents()` takes the iframe window object and localizes it for traversal.